# Shell - Looping Array with command and increment command values

Tags: arrays, shell, unix, scripting

```
    var1=$(echo $getDate | awk '{print $1} {print $2}')
    var2=$(echo $getDate | awk '{print $3} {print $4}')
    var3=$(echo $getDate | awk '{print $5} {print $6}')
```

Instead of repeating like the code above, I need to:

1. loop the same command
2. increment the values *({print $1} {print $2})*
3. store the value in an array

I was doing something like below but I am stuck maybe someone can help me please:

```
COMMAND=`find $locationA -type f | wc -l`
getDate=$(find $locationA -type f | xargs ls -lrt | awk '{print $6} {print $7}')
a=1
b=2
for i in $COMMAND
do
   i=$(echo $getDate | awk '{print $a} {print $b}')
   myarray+=('$i')
   a=$((a+1))
   b=$((b+1))
done
```

**PS - using ksh**

**Problem: $COMMAND stores the number of files found in $locationA. I need to loop through the amount of files found and store their dates in an array.**

Comment: Which shell are you using?

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/087 -- using `xargs ls` is **absolutely** the wrong way to extract metadata. (Finding the N newest files in a safe and portable way is a FAQ of its own, and one there are good solutions for).

Comment: Also, piping from `find` to `xargs ls` will invoke `ls` once per batch of files, where batch size is dependent on your platform's MAX_ARGS, and `ls -t` only sorts within those batches (since one invocation can only sort the arguments that invocation is given).. long and short of it being that in addition to the bugs given in the links above, what you're doing here _also_ doesn't sort files by time correctly if there's more than a certain number of them.

Comment: @anubhava, clearly the shell has arrays and `+=` syntax, so I'm assuming that it's bash (and not tagged as such by error).

Comment: Is this a GNU system? More specifically, can you rely on having GNU stat or GNU find available?

Comment: btw, `for i in $COMMAND` is also badly, badly broken. See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor -- but then, since you're piping into `wc -l`, there'll only be a single thing in `$COMMAND`, a number. What's the point in iterating over the string-split version of a variable that only contains a single number?

Comment: It would perhaps be better to provide an actual problem statement ("I want to accomplish X") rather than a bunch of broken code, and expecting people to figure out what that code is supposed to do. The English description, at present, is still describing "how", not "what".

Comment: To put it a different way: `for i in 5` doesn't run 5 times, it runs once. Thus, `for i in $COMMAND` does the same.

Comment: Thanks guys I have updated what I need exactly maybe it was a bit confusing

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the meaning of your example code (what is the 'for' loop supposed to do? What is the content of the variable COMMAND?), but in your question you ask to store something in an *array*, while in the code you wish to simplify, you don't use an array, but simple variables (var1, var2, ....).

If I understand your requirement correctly, your variable getDate contains a string of several words, which are separated by spaces, and you want to assign the first two words to var1, the following two words to var2, and so on. Is this correct?

Comment: Sorry forgot to include it - Updated it above within the code and basically $COMMAND stores the number of files found within a location. For loop would loop for the amount of files found (already stored in $COMMAND)

Comment: What exactly does it mean, to "loop for the amount of files"? As I already pointed out, your loop would execute exactly once.

Comment: So if it finds 3 files (as being stored in $COMMAND) it loops for 3 times .. maybe I did not write in correct format

Comment: @Sergio M.S.: The way you wrote it, 'wc -l' gets its input from stdin, which means that the output is always a single number, for instance the number 3. Hence, 'for i in 3' would be executed, which means a single execution of the loop, where i is set to the number 3.

Comment: Yes I understood that and I can agree on that .. so in your opinion how can I create a for loop to loop until it matches with the numbers of files found please?

Comment: @Sergio M. S.: As I said, I'm long out of ksh development, and don't know anything about the various current versions (and in particular, you didn't say which ksh version you are using), but doesn't the man page of your ksh give example of counting loops?

Answer (score 0):

Now the edited code is at least a bit clearer, though I still don't understand, why you use i as a loop variable, and overwrite it in the first statement inside the loop.

However, a few comments:

- If you push '$i' into your array, you will get a literal '$' sign, followed by the letter 'i'. To add a variable i containing to numbers, you need double quotes ("$i").
- I don't understand why you want to loop over the cotnent of the variable COMMAND. This variable will always hold a single number, which means that the loop will be executed exactly once.
- You could use a counting loop, incrementing loop variable by 2 on each iteration. You would have to precalculate the number of iterations beforehand.
- Perhaps an easier alternative, which would work in bash or in zsh (I did not try other shells) is to first turn your variable in an array,

  tmparr=($(echo $getDate|fmt -w 1))

and then use a loop to collect pairs of this element:

```
myarray=()
for ((i=0; i<${#tmparr[*]}; i+=2))
do
    myarray+=("${tmparr[$i]} ${tmparr[$((i+1))]}")
done
```

${myarray[0]} will hold a string consisting of the first to words from getDate, etc.

Comment: `foo=( $(bar) )` is not a best-practices way to populate an array -- it not only string-splits on IFS but also expands globs, honoring the `nullglob` setting as it does so. Thus, if `bar` outputs a `*`, you get a list of filenames in the current directory in `foo`; if it contains `[something]`, and if nothing matches and the `nullglob` option is enabled, the word that expression is part of is removed entirely! Using `read -a` to read into arrays is far more reliable.

Comment: @Charles Duffy: Thank you for pointing this out. If you have time to look at my zsh solutions too (the syntax used by the OP doesn't exclude zsh, so I think it makes sense to offer a solution for this too), especially to the second one. I think this would be safe from the pitfalls you describe, due to the (f) modifier. Is this correct?

Comment: Frankly, this the primary reason I stopped using zsh over a decade ago: Deviating from POSIX shells in such a way that things that work correctly in zsh are subtly buggy (but not outright broken!) in shells which comply with POSIX expansion rules gets folks used to practices/habits that get them in trouble when moving to other shells -- but subtle enough trouble that their bugs too-often pass testing.

Comment: Well, it's true that zsh is not POSIX compatible - I personally just see it as a different programming language and recently started to write most of my shell stuff in zsh, simply there are several things which I like better than in POSIX shells. But it is true that we should always establish the context, i.e. which shell we are using, when discussing these issues. In many cases it will even be necessary to state which version of the shell is supposed to be used.....

Answer (score 0):

This one should work on zsh, at least with newer versions:

```
myarray=()
echo $g|fmt -w 1|paste -s -d " \n"|while read s; do myarray+=("$s"); done
```

This leaves the first pair in ${myarray[1]}, etc.

It doesn't work with bash (and old zsh versions), because these shells would execute the body of the loop in a subshell.

ADDED:

On a second thought, in zsh this one would be simpler:

```
myarray=("${(f)$(echo $g|fmt -w 1|paste -s -d ' \n')}")
```

Comment: You could adopt your solution to work with modern bash quite easily, as it happens. `while read -r s; do myarray+=( "$s"); done < <(fmt -w1 <<<"$g" | paste -s -d " \n"`

Comment: ...though it'd be still easier to use `readarray` or `mapfile`, if targeting bash 4: `readarray -t myarray < <(fmt -w1 <<<"$g" | paste -s -d ' \n')`

Comment: ...or you could `shopt -s lastpipe` (again, in recent bash 4.x) to put the right-hand side of the loop in the primary shell (subject to some restrictions, most notably incompatibility with job control); at that point you'd just need quotes around the `echo "$g"` for your stock first answer to work in bash.

Comment: Great! I wasn't even aware that readarray existed (and I just checked it in the man page)!

Comment: @Sergio M.S.: I don't know. I haven't programmed in ksh for ages, and in particular, I don't know the features of the more recent versions.